# How to multiply a timespan by a decimal?

Tags: c#, timespan

I'm working on a project which calculates a cost of calls from two different times entered by the user. I've parsed the data into the code as `DateTime`.

```
        DateTime starttime = new DateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(cal1.SelectedDate).Year,Convert.ToDateTime(cal1.SelectedDate).Month,Convert.ToDateTime(cal1.SelectedDate).Day,
    Convert.ToInt32(drpdwn1.SelectedValue),
    Convert.ToInt32(drpdwn2.SelectedValue),
    Convert.ToInt32(drpdwn3.SelectedValue));

    DateTime endtime = new DateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(cal1.SelectedDate).Year, Convert.ToDateTime(cal1.SelectedDate).Month, Convert.ToDateTime(cal1.SelectedDate).Day,
    Convert.ToInt32(drpdwn4.SelectedValue),
    Convert.ToInt32(drpdwn5.SelectedValue),
    Convert.ToInt32(drpdwn6.SelectedValue));
```

And subtracts the two to get a timespan.

```
            TimeSpan duration3 = (endtime - starttime);
            txtDisplay.Text = duration3.ToString();
```

Can someone help me find a way to multiply $0.35 to the `timespan` **duration3**?
Here is what I'm using right now but the textbox keeps displaying 0

```
 double mins = duration3.Minutes;
        double hrs = duration3.Hours;
        double cost = ((hrs * 60) + mins) * 0.35;
        txtCost.Text = cost.ToString();
        //$0.35/min
        // ((0.35*60)*hr + 0.35*min)
```

Comment: Well, what is the actual thing that you are trying to achieve? is that simply *`multiply $0.35 to the timespan`*

Comment: To start with, it's  not clear why you're creating your `DateTime` values by converting `cal1.SelectedDate` to a `DateTime` *six times*. It's not clear where the `decimal` values comes, as 0.35 is a `double`, not a `decimal`...

Comment: Why do you not use the DateTime from cal1 directly?

I think your problem is the creation of the DateTime struct ...

Comment: I have to use the date of the call selected by the user in the calendar to make a calculation because the cost of calls differ from weekends and weekdays. The call costs are $0.35 for weekends and $0.50 on weekdays.

Comment: @FerdinandBrunauer

Comment: @un-lucky yes I'm trying to multiply that because call cost $0.35/min

Comment: cal1.SelectedDate should already be a DateTime. All of your Convert.ToDateTime methods are redundant. You even could use the ctor: new Datetime(year, month, day, hours, ...)

Comment: I am *super confused* by your code; why are you extracting hours and minutes and then converting hours to minutes, blah blah blah, instead of simply extracting `TotalMinutes`???

Answer (score 2):

Possibly something like:

```
static decimal Foo(TimeSpan duration, decimal perMinuteRate)
    => ((decimal)duration.TotalMinutes) * perMinuteRate;
```

although note that `TotalMinutes` is a `double`, so this could have unexpected rounding if your duration is very fractional.

Comment: Why ticks? he is operating on a per-minute based Cost... and the code from the questions clearly shows hes not using the seconds at all :)

Comment: @FerdinandBrunauer you could do that, but you'd need to factor to get the appropriate scales; perfectly doable, of course - feel free to add as an answer :)

Comment: would it make sense to explicitly use `duration.Duration.TotalMinutes` to avoid calculating negative amounts of money?

Comment: It is wise to use Ticks just because it is undercover representation of TimeSpan. Entire class is just a wrapper, so TotalMinutes is calculatable property rather than serialized value. It also includes errors in precision. So, using simple *long* typed ticks is much better solution in accuracy and performance, and do not include double precision errors, cause all multiplication are performed over digital types, especially when person work with decimal and money.

Comment: For conversion with ticks, the struct has the `TicksPerMinute` constant which has type `long` and value `600000000L`.

Comment: Note that eocron's point is not merely an implementation detail, but a _documented_ implementation detail.  Per the remarks section of [MSDN:TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx), "The value of a TimeSpan object is the number of ticks that equal the represented time interval. "

Answer (score 1):

Better to do it this way, so you don't interfer with double precision errors:

```
public static decimal MultiplyPerMinute(TimeSpan a, decimal b)
{
    return a.Ticks * b / TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute;
}
```

When you work with decimal, only double or float **should** scare you off in any possible operator. Decimal is a type made specificaly for digital, and precision durable operations.

Comment: Sorry, edited answer, just overthinking led to FromTicks. Overkill? Probably, but it is a lot faster and simplier for compiler than using property with double return type. Which, can lead to very funny artifacts.

Comment: Looks fine now . Still wouldnt use TICKs for clarity of intend reasons. Using TimeSpan.TotalMinutes is MUCH easier to comprehend for any fellow code refactorer than the ticks stuff - and the internal conversion-overhead should not matter at all unless your application does this task as its main task. For me its kindof `premature optimization` regarding clean code rules. removed my -1 though.

Comment: There is no problem with optimization, I didn't even consider to optimize anything in such small operation. There is problem with precision using double and decimal. So, you can pretty much lose pretty-penny if you working with money, for example.

Answer (score 0):

As written, the question is not very clear. There are two questions really:

1. How to multiply a TimeSpan by a decimal?
2. Why is my TextBox always displaying zero?

Question 1 is not clear - it can be interpreted in many ways. From reading the posted code, comments and other answers it is possible to see that you are trying to calculate the "cost of a TimeSpan given the cost per minute". Why not ask this question?

But that isn't really your question - your posted code does indicate that you have an idea about how to calculate the "cost of a TimeSpan given the cost per minute", the problem is that your "textbox keeps displaying 0".

From the code posted, I don't know why this is. However, following some good debugging practices should fairly quickly help you narrow down the problem yourself.

See this link to a post by Eric Lippert that you should find useful:
[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score -1):

No need to calculate the minutes yourself - and multiplying is easy:

```
        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Today;
        var cost = ((int)ts.TotalMinutes)  * 0.35m; // cost per minute, edited wrongly used 0.63m
```

I am `int` ing out the decimals of TotalMinutes to avoid billing for 23.2832s as well ;)

Comment: such hard coded numbers is not good practice. later you have to think how you come up with `0.63`. this number may look _meaningless_ because you oversimplified it. if you use constants instead, compiler will take care of simplification and you still have your _meaningful_ formula.

Comment: minor note: `0.63` is a `double`, not a `decimal`; `0.63M` is a decimal

Comment: for the sake of further rounding problems --- I agree. Thx for the pointer  @MarcGravell